# Is there a field $K$ and a quadratic polynomial $f\in K[T]$ such that $f^2+1$ is a square in $K[T]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is there a field $K$ (ideally a number field not containing $i$) such that there is a quadratic polynomial $f = T^2 + aT + b\in K[T]$ satisfying the property that $f^2+1$ is also a square in $K[T]$?

For various complicated reasons my investigations has led me to consider this problem...

Comment: If $K$ has characteristic two, $f^2 + 1$ is always a square, namely $f^2 + 1 = (f + 1)^2$. In this case, $K$ is not a number field, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if $K$ has characteristic $\ne 2$.

If $f^2+1=g^2$, then $1=(f+g)(f-g)$ has degree $0$, but at least one of $f\pm g$ has degree $\ge 2$.

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP asked for (preferably) a number field

Comment: Yes...preferably though doesn't work as in characteristic different from two, as you show, things don't work.

Comment: Then do function fields like $F_2[u]$ count?

Comment: @FanZheng That isn't the usual, standard notation for function fields. Anyway, if you want $\;\Bbb F_2(t)\;$ then this is **still** a field of characteristic two and this will work here. In fact, $\;\Bbb F_2[t]\subset\Bbb F_2(t)\;$ and the latter is the quotient field of the former.

Comment: I mean $\mathbb{F}_2(u)$ of course, because the OP has already used $T$.

Comment: @FanZheng Exactly the same as my past comment applies here with $\;u\;$ instead of $\;t\;$...unless you have $\;u\;$ is an algebraic element over $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ in is algebraic closure, say.

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean in $\mathbb{F}_2(u)$ you do have such an example, and I don't know if the OP considers function fields cousins of number fields.

Comment: @FanZheng If he considers them so then I think they are remote, very remote related cousins...anyway, we **still** have the same example here:$$f:=u^2\in\Bbb F_2[u]\subset\Bbb F_2(u)\;,\;\;f^2+1=(f+1)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Of course:

$$f(t)=t^2\in\Bbb F_2[t]\implies f^2+1=t^4+1=(t^2+1)^2\in\Bbb F_2[t]$$

As a rule: where squares kick in in "tricky" ways, characteristic $\;2\;$ is what will likely render results

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it unless char $K=2$.

Simply compare coefficients of $f^2+1=(T^2+cT+d)^2$. You get $2a=2c$, $a^2+2b=c^2+2d$, and you can divide by 2 to conclude $a=c$ and $b=d$, but then the identity can not hold.

If char $K=2$, it is always true: $f^2+1=(f+1)^2$.